# undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass can't find the id of my data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table that users can add data to, I've also included a button for users to delete a row of data:

```
<tbody>
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to job.job_title, job.url, :target => "_blank" %></td>
    <td><%= job.company %></td>
    <td><%= job.location %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "", list_url(job), method: :delete, class: "fa fa-trash-o" %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
```

However when the delete button is pressed I get a "undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass" error. In my server logs it says that the ID is null and I can't seem to grab the id of that particular row of data.

I've looked at other similar Stackoverflow questions to the one I am asking but the solutions found there haven't worked for me.

For reference here are my routes that relate to adding, showing and deleting data:

```
get '/jobs' => 'search#list', as: 'list'
post '/jobs' => 'search#create'
delete '/jobs' => 'search#destroy'
```

And my controller:

```
def new
  @job = Job.new
end

def create
  @job = Job.new(job_params)

  if @job.save
    redirect_to list_url, notice: "You've successfully added the job to the list"
  else
    render 'search', notice: "Something went wrong, please try again"
  end
end

def list
  @jobs = Job.all
  @job = Job.find_by_id(params[:id])
end

def destroy
  @job = Job.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @job.destroy
  redirect_to list_url, notice: "Job destroyed"
end

def job_params
  params.require(:job).permit(:job_title, :company, :location, :url)
end
```

Comment: Please post the error message and where it occurs.

Comment: It occurs at `@job.destroy` in my controller 

The error says "NoMethodError in SearchController#destroy, undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: you know the difference when using `find_by_id` and `find`? `find_by_id` returns even not found and raise no error. `find` crashes. so you have to make sure that there is a record found when using `find_by_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your delete link, you want to link to the object itself, not the URL to the object.  So change

```
<td><%= link_to "", list_url(job), method: :delete, class: "fa fa-trash-o" %></td>
```

to

```
<td><%= link_to "", job, method: :delete, class: "fa fa-trash-o" %></td>
```

On top of that, you'll need the appropriate `CRUD` routes defined, so I would recommend the following in your `routes.rb` file:

```
resources :jobs, controller: 'search'
```

Comment: I get a "undefined method `job_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f8669b78350>:0x007f866c189350>" when I made the change

Comment: You need a `delete` route for `/job` (singular) in your `routes.rb`

Comment: I switched `delete '/jobs' => 'search#destroy'` to this: 

`delete '/job' => 'search#destroy'` and got the same error I originally had. 

I also tried changing the route to `delete '/job/:id' => 'search#destroy'` but I get a routing error saying "No route matches [DELETE] "/jobs.4""

Comment: I think @JacobM is right about not having a show route.  I would recommend using `resources :jobs, controller: 'search'` instead of individual route commands.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to implement the functionality without the full crud resources, but it seems that in leaving some of them out I am getting problems. I'll try the solution you mentioned.

Comment: Always start simple, and then pear it back if needed.  :)

Comment: Haha good advice, after I added `resources :jobs, controller: 'search'` and changed some files and links to the appropriate names I got it to work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you want to link to `list_url` if you're trying to specify a particular instance of job.  Maybe something like

```
<td><%= link_to "", job_path(job), method: :delete, class: "fa fa-trash-o" %></td>
```

Comment: When I made the change I get the same error I posted for @Donovan 's answer

Comment: I think that's an issue with your routes.  It looks like you have a list route but not a show route.